# how codeigniter call postgresql function

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter

Postresql  function

```
  SELECT payroll.leave_sufix_prefix('234','2014-05-09')
```

how to call it for codeigniter model

Answer (score 2):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM my_function()");
```

Comment: You should explain it as well rather than just one line of code,